# Regex check if link is to a file

Tags: python, html, regex, hyperlink

How to check if a given link (url) is to file or another webpage?

I mean:

- page: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
- page: *https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp*
- file: *https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/python-3.7.2.exe*
- file :*http://jmlr.org/papers/volume19/16-534/16-534.pdf#page=15*

Currently I am doing it with a quite hacky, multi-step checking, and it also requires converting relative to absolute links, adding http prefix if missing and removing '#' anchor links/params to work. I am also **not sure if I'm whitelisting all possible page extensions that exist**.

```
import re
def check_file(url):
    try:
        sub_domain = re.split('\/+', url)[2] # part after '2nd slash(es)''
    except:
        return False # nothing = main page, no file
    if not re.search('\.', sub_domain):
        return False # no dot, no file
    if re.search('\.htm[l]{0,1}$|\.php$|\.asp$', sub_domain):
        return False # whitelist some page extensions
    return True

tests = [
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com/randomlink',
    'https:////www.stackoverflow.com//page.php',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com/page.html',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com/page.htm',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com/file.exe',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com/image.png'
]

for test in tests:
    print(test + '\n' + str(check_file(test)))
# False: https://www.stackoverflow.com
# False: https://www.stackoverflow.com/randomlink
# False: https:////www.stackoverflow.com//page.php
# False: https://www.stackoverflow.com/page.html
# False: https://www.stackoverflow.com/page.htm
# True: https://www.stackoverflow.com/file.exe
# True: https://www.stackoverflow.com/image.png
```

Is there a *clean, single regex match solution* to this problem or a library with an *established function* to do it? I guess someone must have faced this problem before me, but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution here on SO or else.

Comment: I don't think you can unambiguously determine the type of data that a url will give you, just by looking at the url. If a web server really wants to, it can decide to serve an html file when you visit "image.png". Or it can serve an mp3 when you go to "page.htm". Or any other combination of file types and extensions. To get accurate type data, you'd need to check the http header's MIME type.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin , apparently I've been trying to solve the wrong problem. I guess I 'll do what you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aran-Fey's answer works well on well-behaved pages, which make up 99.99% of the web. But there's no rule that says a url ending with a particular extension must resolve to content of a particular type. A poorly-configured server could return html for a request to a page named "example.png", or it could return an mpeg for a page named "example.php", or any other combination of content types and file extensions.

The most accurate way to get content type information for a url is to actually visit that url and examine the content type in its header. Most http-interfacing libraries have a way to retrieve only the header information from a site, so this operation should be relatively quick even for very large pages. For example, if you were using `requests`, you might do:

```
import requests
def get_content_type(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    return response.headers['Content-Type']

test_cases = [
    "http://www.example.com",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3HH6.png?s=328&g=1",
    "http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php",
]    

for url in test_cases:
    print("Url:", url)
    print("Content type:", get_content_type(url))
```

Result:

```
Url: http://www.example.com
Content type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3HH6.png?s=328&g=1
Content type: image/png
Url: http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php
Content type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

[`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) is your friend.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def check_file(url):
    path = urlparse(url).path  # extract the path component of the URL
    name = path.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]  # discard everything before the last slash

    if '.' not in name:  # if there's no . it's definitely not a file
        return False

    ext = path.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]  # extract the file extension
    return ext not in {'htm', 'html', 'php', 'asp'}
```

This can be simplified further with the use of the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import PurePath

def check_file(url):
    path = PurePath(urlparse(url).path)
    ext = path.suffix[1:]

    if not ext:
        return False

    return ext not in {'htm', 'html', 'php', 'asp'}
```